# Is it possible to have Google Assistant work with screen off?

Tags: google-assistant

When I'm out and about, I usually have wireless headphones (with mic) on, and my phone in my pocket, usually listening to a podcast.

Quite often I want to add something to my todo list- and I'd like to have Google Assistant do that for me.

But the problem is that it seems that Google Assistant requires screen on to work - is it possible to get around this?

Comment: So do you have a headset with Google Assistant support: https://support.google.com/headphones/answer/9027902?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en Also see: https://9to5google.com/2017/09/29/how-to-google-assistant-headphones-instruction-videos/

Comment: Also make sure your settings are correct per link below. Samsung phones seem to have an issue. [Edit] to add device. https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/387976?hl=en

Comment: @MorrisonChang Ok - cool, that looks like it answers the question. Feel free to post an answer saying that it needs to be a 'made for google' device, and a link to those instructions, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Assistant with features as shown in this article on [Google Assistant headset instruction videos](https://9to5google.com/2017/09/29/how-to-google-assistant-headphones-instruction-videos/) you'll need to be using `Headphones optimized for the Google Assistant` or `Made for Google`:

See: [Official Google Assistant on Headphones Documentation](https://support.google.com/headphones/answer/9027902?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)